# System of linear equations problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Consider the system of linear equations:
\begin{align}
\begin{cases}
x+ay=1\\[2ex] 
bx+5y=2,
\end{cases}
\end{align}
where $a$ and $b$ are parameters.

(a) Determine the conditions on $a$ and $b$ to get a unique solution. 
(b) Determine the conditions on $a$ and $b$ to get infinitely many solutions. 
(c) Determine the conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that the system has no solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Answer:

a) $$ab\not=5$$. The determinant of the matrix  not equal to zero.  There is a unique solution

b)$$a = \frac{5}{2}, b=2$$  The determinant is zero, but the two lines are identical, There are infinitely many solution

c) $$ab = 5 \land \lnot (a = \frac{5}{2} \land b=2)$$   The determinant is zero, but the two lines are parallel.  There are no solutions

The determinant => (5-ab)

Comment: c) should be $ab = 5 \land \lnot(a = \frac{5}{2} \land b = 2)$.

Comment: You are right, I do not know the syntax.  If you don't mind, could you edit my answer

Comment: @Keba, Thanks.  I appreciate it!!

Comment: Done. :) Btw: $\land$ is `land`, $\lnot$ is `lnot`. Most times `l` (for logical, I assume) + "that what you assume" does the job for these symbols. There is also [Detextify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html).

Answer (score 1):

Let's write the equations as follows:
$$x+ay=1\\
bx+5y=2$$
So, one has
$$\begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\ b & 5\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}\\
\implies \begin{pmatrix}x\\ y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & a\\ b & 5\end{pmatrix}^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}=\dfrac{1}{5-ab}\begin{pmatrix}5 & -a\\ -b & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\ 2\end{pmatrix}$$
This should considerably simplify your solution. As a hint, look at the term $\dfrac{1}{5-ab}$ on the RHS.